# Another url is been appended to my url when i click a link

Tags: php, url

My site is farmers.areashoppers.co. when I click certain links (Home (index.php), and buy crops (buy-crops.php)) another url is appended to the url I intend to go to. Example when home to get to index.php, the url that appears in the address bar becomes farmers.areashoppers.co/farmers.areashoppers.co instead of just farmers.areashoppers.co. Any help is appreciated.

I believe the problem is being caused by this htacces file

`

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 406 /

Options -Indexes

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files composer.json>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files composer.lock>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    </Files>

<Files .env>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

`

Is there anyway i can override the rule that is causing the problem with another htaccess file in the subdomain's folder. The htaccess file is a laravel file. Thanks

Comment: The links themselves appear to point to correct URLs. But then your system issues a HTTP redirect with status code 301, to the faulty addresses. We can not tell you from the outside, why that might happen - so you will need to check your code / configuration. If you have any rewriting in place on the webserver level (like configured in a .htaccess on an Apache webserver), that would probably be a good place to start looking.

Comment: When you hover/mouseover the links, does it already show `farmers.areashoppers.co/farmers.areashoppers.co` at the bottom? Is the link correct but gets redirected once you hit the url?

Comment: Hi CBroe. Ive posted an htaccess file (belonging to laravel) that may be causing the problem. Please look at the htaccess file and show me how i can override the directive that is causing the error in my subdomain/sub folder

Answer (score -1):

I think you have use javascript. When you click on button it will append the url and redirect to that url.

Please make sure when you click a button and want to redirect somewhere your existing url should be blank